# Access Database is not getting updated, or read

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ms-access

I am a beginner in `C#`, just learnt it for school project, and now I am trying to work on a login application project for school, but cannot seem to get my database of access to update, or get read.

Whenever I update the password, it shows that password was updated successfully, but it doesn't reflect in my database.

All the DB connection strings and table references are correct, I triple checked. Can anyone help?

BTW yes i open my access DB from the *BIN* folder in my project solution file directory, read somewhere that it helps. but it inst helping right now.

Code for the Update button click event

```
con.Open();
if (txtNewPassword.Text == txtConfirmPassword.Text)
{
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("update LoginDeets set [Password] = '" + txtNewPassword.Text + "' where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'", con);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   lblErrMsg.Text = "Data Updated Successfully";
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: If the execution of the SQL is successful and no rows are updated, double check your `Where` clause. Are you absolutely certain the `txtUserName.Text` matches a record?

Comment: Don't concatenate the SQL statement like that. Create [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) for each and add them to the [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). Note, `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` must return a non-zero value to say `Data Updated Successfully`. Read the OleDB docs to master it.

Comment: check what is being returned by  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
int rowsAffected=  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().
If something is updated in db, then it should be greater than 0

Comment: If you are running your project in Visual Studio, check the "copy to output" setting of the database. Set it to "do not copy" and also set the "datasource" in the connection string to the fixed address.

Comment: Do not persist passwords. Not even on a Training Mission. Never. It's wrong. If you want to play around with db then save birth dates or something. Passwords are not for the db.

Comment: How did you decide "it doesn't reflect in my database"? There is nothing here that reads a database. Are you looking at the database yourself? How are you doing that?

Answer (score 4):

Please heed the recommendations in the comments and rather than work with passwords consider working with things like reading, adding and updating a person table were the data is not sensitive like passwords are.

**Important**: DO NOT simply copy and paste the presented code and simply use it, instead make sure you understand the code and then adapt to what you are doing without involving passwords.

When inserting a new record, use the value returned from `ExecuteNonQuery` which returns an int. So for inserting one row the value should be 1. If 1 then we can also get the new primary key. Given a table with an primary key of Id and two string columns FirstName and LastName we can write the following code.

**Connection variable**

```cs
public static string ConnectionString =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database1.accdb";
```

All code below was written using .NET Core 7

**Add method**

```cs
public static (bool success, int) InsertRow(string firstName, string lastName)
{

    using OleDbConnection cn = new() { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
    using OleDbCommand cmd = new() { Connection = cn };

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@FirstName",
        DbType = DbType.String
    }).Value = firstName;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@LastName",
        DbType = DbType.String
    }).Value = lastName;
        
    cmd.CommandText = 
        @"INSERT INTO Person (FirstName,LastName) 
          VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";


    cn.Open();

    // insert new row
    int affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // validate insert worked
    if (affected == 1)
    {
        // insert successful, get new primary key
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@Identity";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        return (true, reader.GetInt32(0));
    }
    else
    {
        // insert failed
        return (false, -1);
    }
}
```

**Update row**

Then for update we check the value for `ExecuteNonQuery` which in the case of updating one record will be 1.

```cs
public static bool UpdateRow(int identifier, string firstName, string lastName)
{

    using OleDbConnection cn = new() { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
    using OleDbCommand cmd = new() { Connection = cn };

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@FirstName",
        DbType = DbType.String
    }).Value = firstName;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@LastName",
        DbType = DbType.String
    }).Value = lastName;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@Id",
        DbType = DbType.Int16
    }).Value = identifier;

    cmd.CommandText =
        @"UPDATE Person 
          SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName 
          WHERE id = @Id";


    cn.Open();

    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1;
}
```

Read data

```cs
public static DataTable GetAll()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using OleDbConnection cn = new() { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
    using OleDbCommand cmd = new() { Connection = cn };
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Person";
    cn.Open();
    table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    return table;
}
```

In regards to ensuring you are looking at the right database, for a .NET Core project, there should be a item group for the database as follows.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Database1.accdb">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Which is from setting the property `Copy to output Directory` to `Copy if Newer` and if you do not the code still works but is overwritten when running the project again.

See also Visual Studio: [Copying files to Debug or Release folder](https://dev.to/karenpayneoregon/visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder-3onj)

**Form code**

All the code above was written in a class file named `DataOperations.cs`

```cs
using System.Data;

namespace YourNamespaceGoesHere;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var (success, identifier) = DataOperations.InsertRow("Frank", "Smith");
        if (success)
        {
            // identifier has the new primary key
        }
        else
        {
            // failed
        }
    }

    private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = DataOperations.UpdateRow(3, "Karen", "Smith");
        if (result)
        {
            // updated
        }
        else
        {
            // failed
        }
    }

    private void ReadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = DataOperations.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! im really new to working with C#, its only been a couple of days, so this really helps, although it still feels a bit overwhelming to read and understand stuff like this